# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_adjustMaxNumberOfFiles' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload, actionlink

I'm using the jQuery-fileupload from here (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)
Everything is working fine until i try to open the Ajax-Link to the fileupload in a new window... I've debugged the code in question:

```
    $.getJSON($('#fileupload form').prop('action'), function (files) {
        var fu = $('#fileupload').data('fileupload');
        fu._adjustMaxNumberOfFiles(-files.length);
        fu._renderDownload(files)
            .appendTo($('#fileupload .files'))
            .fadeIn(function () {
                // Fix for IE7 and lower:
                $(this).show();
            });
    });
```

As the Debugger tells me the files are received but well ... "fu" is null.
Checked if all scripts are loaded and they are.

the Razor markup:

```
<div id="fileupload">
<form action="~/Upload/UploadHandler.ashx?Action=SedCard&thumb=1" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="fileupload-buttonbar">
        <label class="fileinput-button">
            <span>Add files...</span>
            <input id="btnAdd" type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" />
        </label>
        <button type="button" class="delete button">Delete all files</button>
        <div class="fileupload-progressbar"></div>
    </div>
</form>
<div class="fileupload-content">
    <table class="files"></table>
</div>
```

Controller Code:

```
    <HttpGet> _
    <Authorize> _
    Function MyUpload() As ActionResult
        If Request.IsAjaxRequest Then
            Return PartialView("_MyUpload")
        Else
            Return View("_MyUpload")
        End If
    End Function
```

So, if i run this in PartialView everything is going fine but running it in a new window as View it will throw that error.

Does anyone have an idea whats going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Oh Lord, I found the problem...

Turned out that the document wasn't completely loaded when the $getJSON ran.
So in case someone else is banging their head...

```html
 $(document).ready(function () {
         $.getJSON($('#fileupload form').prop('action'), function (files) {
            var fu = $('#fileupload').data('fileupload');
            fu._adjustMaxNumberOfFiles(-files.length);
            fu._renderDownload(files)
                .appendTo($('#fileupload .files'))
                .fadeIn(function () {
                    // Fix for IE7 and lower:
                    $(this).show();
                });
        });

    });
```

Everything is working now :D